# c# how to access all instances of a class outside of the function?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to C# and OOP, in general, I've kinda hit a wall I am reading in this CSV using the CSV Helper package, but there are some unwanted rows, etc so I have cleaned it up by iterating over "records" and creating a new class LineItems.

But Now I appear to be a bit stuck. I know void doesn't return anything and is a bit of a placeholder. But How can I access all the instances of LineItems outside of this function?

```
public void getMapper()
        {
            using (var StreamReader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Data\Projects\dictUnitMapper.csv"))
            {
                using (var CsvReader = new CsvReader(StreamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    var records = CsvReader.GetRecords<varMapper>().ToList();
               
                foreach (var item in records)
                {
                    if (item.name != "#N/A" && item.priority != 0)
                    {
                        LineItems lineItem = new LineItems();

                        lineItem.variableName = item.Items;
                        lineItem.variableUnit = item.Unit;
                        lineItem.variableGrowthCheck = item.growth;
                        lineItem.variableAVGCheck = item.avg;
                        lineItem.variableSVCheck = item.svData;
                        lineItem.longName = item.name;
                        lineItem.priority = item.priority;
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    public class LineItems
    {
        public string variableName;
        public string variableUnit;
        public bool variableGrowthCheck;
        public bool variableAVGCheck;
        public bool variableSVCheck;
        public string longName;
        public int priority;
    }

    public class varMapper
    {

        public string Items { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public bool growth { get; set; }
        public bool avg { get; set; }
        public bool svData { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int priority { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you *need* to map the records to different property names? Hint CsvReader supports `[Name("name")]` attributes. Or do you just need to filter rows `.Where(i => i.name != "#N/A" ....`

Comment: You should create a property, private when possible, that you can store the new items in.

Comment: Can you link me to some documentation bionic regarding that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your method to return a list.

```
public List<LineItems> GetMapper()
{
    using (var StreamReader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Data\Projects\dictUnitMapper.csv"))
    {
        using (var CsvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(StreamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            return
                CsvReader
                    .GetRecords<varMapper>()
                    .Where(item => item.name != "#N/A")
                    .Where(item => item.priority != 0)
                    .Select(item => new LineItems()
                    {

                        variableName = item.Items,
                        variableUnit = item.Unit,
                        variableGrowthCheck = item.growth,
                        variableAVGCheck = item.avg,
                        variableSVCheck = item.svData,
                        longName = item.name,
                        priority = item.priority,
                    })
                    .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an alternative syntax for building the return value:

```
            return
            (
                from item in CsvReader.GetRecords<varMapper>()
                where item.name != "#N/A"
                where item.priority != 0
                select new LineItems()
                {
                    variableName = item.Items,
                    variableUnit = item.Unit,
                    variableGrowthCheck = item.growth,
                    variableAVGCheck = item.avg,
                    variableSVCheck = item.svData,
                    longName = item.name,
                    priority = item.priority,
                }
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: How would I access this list from another page? Although let me clarify I would like to load the data in only once( i.e read the csv once then have the list in memory and access that)

Comment: @JPWilson - Just keep a reference to the returned list. Probably as a private field. Is that what you want?